# Should HTTP 4xx responses imply no change in application state?

Tags: api, rest, http, validation, web-applications

If a web application returns an HTTP 4xx response back to the client should the client assume that the communication was stateless? If this is true, should web applications return a 5xx response in the case where a client's request results in a state change but further processing fails due to an issue with the client's request (we can assume that top layer validation cannot detect this case and recovery is not possible).

Is there an ISO standard developers can refer to that discusses what is expected as far as application state is concerned when an HTTP 4xx is returned? Is this covered in RESTful architecture?

Answer (score 0):

So, working backwards -- the semantics of 5xx response messages and 4xx response messages provide the same guarantees about changes to resource state.
For instance, [HTTP caches](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-cache-19#section-4.4) will treat both 4xx and 5xx as an "error response".

HTTP standardizes the meanings (semantics) of HTTP response codes, but it doesn't constrain implementations - your server is free to return whatever message you want, so long as you describe the message you return appropriately.

If you are expecting *general purpose* clients to understand that there was a problem with the request itself; then you should normally choose to respond with a representation that explains the actual problem, and use the correct HTTP meta data (including the response code) so that intelligent clients can do useful things.

The fact that your server actually did some work that changed the state of the exposed resources is "just" an implementation concern.  There's fundamentally no difference between the case you describe, and the case where this request had no effect, but some *other* request to the server made changes that this client doesn't know about (yet).

If you want the general purpose client to understand that the resource has changed (and that previously cached responses should no longer be used), then you need to return a response with a [non-error status code](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-cache-19#section-4.4).

---

At a higher level, the important idea to understand is that a REST API is a facade - it provides the illusion that our sophisticated service is "just" an HTTP compatible document store.